# SQL query based on three tables with restriction

Tags: sql

I have three tables as follows

- Patient (PatientNo, FamilyName, LastName, Address, State, PostCode)
- Doctor (DoctorNo, Name)
- Account (AccountNo, DoctorNo, PatientID, AccountType)

How do I achieve this?

Get `Name` and `State` of `Patients` who live in the state `WA` and have been treated by `Dr. John` or `Dr. Sara`

Below is my query

```
SELECT 
    FamilyName || ' ' || lastname AS FullName, 
    P.Address, P.state,
    D.name 
FROM
    Patient P 
LEFT JOIN 
    account A ON A.patientno = P.patientno
LEFT J OIN
    Doctor D ON A.DoctorNo = D.DoctorNo 
WHERE
    P.state = 'WA'
    AND D.name = 'John' OR D.name = 'Sara'
```

Comment: Where is `ProviderNo` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the property name in Account table as PatientNo.

```
SELECT 
FamilyName || ' ' || lastname AS FullName, 
P.Address, P.state,
D.name 
FROM
Patient P 
JOIN 
account A ON A.patientno = P.patientno
JOIN
Doctor D ON A.DoctorNo= D.DoctorNo
WHERE
P.state = 'WA'
AND D.name = 'John' OR D.name = `Sara`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct, but you'll need to put brackets in your WHERE clause.

Currently it's doing `(P.state = 'WA' AND D.name = 'John') OR D.name = 'Sara'`. Therefore finding

- all patients for John in WA, and
- all patients for Sara, whether or not they're in WA.

I suggest `P.state = 'WA' AND (D.name = 'John' OR D.name = 'Sara')` or even `P.state = 'WA' AND D.name IN ('John', 'Sara')`.

Also note that in your Account table you have `PatientId` but elsewhere you use `PatientNo`. I presume this is a typo, but please check your tables.